# Ssh client config, common configuration for all hosts on the same machine

Tags: ssh, hostname, hosting

in my `~/.ssh/config` I would like to define something like this

```
# myvm.hosting.com is a real existing domain
Host myvm.hosting.com
  # tunnel to mysql
  LocalForward 3311 localhost:3306

# example.com is a real existing domain
Host example.com
  User myuser
  HostName myvm.hosting.com

# example.org is a real existing domain
Host example.org
  User myuser
  HostName myvm.hosting.com
```

When I run `ssh example.com` I would like to execute the port forwarding defined for the `myvm.hosting.com`, but it looks like `HostName` is not overriding `Host`...

Ho to achive this?

PS:

- `Host *` is not an option cause I have many *"base machines"* like `myvm.hosting.com`
- I would like to keep using real DNS, I don't want niknames

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Settings before the first `host` apply to all connections

```
  LocalForward 3311 localhost:3306

# myvm.hosting.com is a real existing domain
Host myvm.hosting.com
  # tunnel to mysql

# example.com is a real existing domain
Host example.com
  User myuser
  HostName myvm.hosting.com

# example.org is a real existing domain
Host example.org
  User myuser
  HostName myvm.hosting.com
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to set different ports for different *"base machines"*